# WP7 How to change the color of the second header of a pivot item

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

Is it possible to have the foreground of the header of a panorama control in red and the other title (that we can start to see because it's a pivot item) in grey for example ?

Title 1 : in red and the shaded title2 in grey.

Thank you

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, are you looking to alter the Header of a Pivot control or Panorama control?

Comment: A pivot control. You see when you design a pivot control you can have many pivot item and for each one a header. Then when you see the first pivot item on your screen, you can start to see the title of the second pivot item. This is the title color of this second pivot item that i want to change

Comment: for example in [link](http://www.google.fr/imgres?q=pivot+item&um=1&hl=fr&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&biw=1920&bih=1070&tbm=isch&tbnid=_CS1ZOzMHQa5iM:&imgrefurl=http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/metroradio-design/&docid=Tw9aJ-I273UZaM&imgurl=http://media.jeff.wilcox.name/blog/2012/SmallPivotThings.png&w=432&h=334&ei=XUahT9oLxp06wb_ZXg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1208&vpy=366&dur=2269&hovh=197&hovw=255&tx=159&ty=103&sig=113460401939224594919&page=1&tbnh=142&tbnw=184&start=0&ndsp=46&ved=1t:429,r:16,s:0,i:101) I want metro to be red while stations stay white

Comment: I have edited my answer inline with your specific requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SelectionChanged event handler. If you define your Headers as TextBlocks :-

```
                <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION"
                    SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="first"
                           Foreground="Red" />
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="second"
                           Foreground="Red" />
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="third"
                           Foreground="Red" />
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="fourth"
                           Foreground="Red" />
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

You can then alter the Foreground of the TextBlocks, in the C# code behind :-

```
        private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (currentItem != null)
            {
                (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
        }

        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (currentItem != null)
            {
                (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, It works but only when I already cross all the items once in my pivot control. EDIT :  Actually It works when I have an item in removedItems. How can I put all the items but the first in RemovedItems at the beginning of my screen

Comment: This is only the basics, you will need to play around with it slighly to fit your needs.

Comment: Just use a loop and color all items except the SelectedIndex

Answer (score 1):

You can wirte the xaml file like this:

```
    <controls:Pivot Title="My application" Foreground="Red">
        <controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="first" Foreground="Gray"></TextBlock>
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="content"></TextBlock>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```